# Exception while using mobile commands for backdoor in Appium-Java

Tags: java, automation, appium

I am trying to use appium backdoor in appium-java client, but exceptions are thrown due to invalid syntax. can someone help me in validating this issue?

```
driver.executeScript("mobile:backdoor", "{target: 'com.learn.android.Settings', methods: [{name: 'setclient' , args: [{value: '10.10.10.10:1010', type: 'java.lang.String'}] }, {name: 'setserver', args: [{value: '19.19.19.19:1919', type: 'java.lang.String'}] }] }");
```

I tried using hashmap but still, I couldn't able to succeed

```
HashMap<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    param.put("target", "com.learn.android.Settings");
    param.put("methods", "[{\n" +
            " \t\t\"name\": \"setclient\",\n" +
            " \t\t\"args\": [{\n" +
            " \t\t\t\"value\": \"10.10.10.10:1010\",\n" +
            " \t\t\t\"type\": \"java.lang.String\"\n" +
            " \t\t}]\n" +
            " \t},\n" +
            " \t{\n" +
            " \t\t\"name\": \"setserver\",\n" +
            " \t\t\"args\": [{\n" +
            " \t\t\t\"value\": \"19.19.19.19:1919\",\n" +
            " \t\t\t\"type\": \"java.lang.String\"\n" +
            " \t\t}]\n" +
            " \t}\n" +
            " ]");

    driver.executeScript("mobile:backdoor", param);
```

appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

Able to find the answer

```
ImmutableMap<String, Object> scriptArgs = ImmutableMap.of(
            "target", "application",
            "methods", Arrays.asList(ImmutableMap.of(
                    "name", "setclient",
                    "args", Arrays.asList(ImmutableMap.of(
                            "value", "2.2.2.2",
                            "type", "String"
                    ))
            ))
    );

    driver.executeScript("mobile: backdoor", scriptArgs);
```